# Wordpress taxonomy archive throws 404

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom taxonomy 'categories' assigned to a custom post type 'food'. I've created a template 'taxonomy-categories.php'. If I set the permalinks to 'simple', the archive of my taxonomy is working. But if I set the permalinks to 'postname', wordpress throws a 404 error. As an example, mydomain.com/food/summer/ doesn't work, but mydomain.com/?categories=summer is working and shows the content from taxonomy-categories.php.

Here's my code:

```
add_action('init', 'post_type_food');
function post_type_food() {
    register_post_type('food',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Rezepte',
                'singular_name' => 'Rezept'
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
            'has_archive' => true
        )
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'categories', array('food'), array(
        'hierarchical' => true, 
        'label' => 'Categories', 
        'singular_label' => 'Category', 
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'food', 'with_front'=> false )
        )
    );
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to refresh the permalinks?
in Settings->permalink, you just click on save

Comment: Yes,I tried it several times

Comment: Try to use a different name for the Categories, maybe it is because it is use by wp. register_taxonomy( 'foodcat'

Comment: Renamed to 'foodcat', refreshed the permalinks, but still 404 :/

Comment: I've found the problem. The name of the post type and the slug of the taxonomy were identical. I renamed the slug, now it works.